# Como ordenar em lista alfabética minha lista em Java?

Tags: java, spring, java-8

Estou com um projeto Spring Framework, e preciso colocar minha lista em ordem alfabética, e não tenho ideia de como fazer. A princípio consegui carregar a lista, mas ela tem que ter essa ordem. Por favor, como devo fazer?

```
@GET
@Path("/tipos-debitos")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Permission(grupo = {Grupo.ADMINISTRADOR})
public Response listarDebitosMultas() {
    final TipoDebitoMultaTO to = new TipoDebitoMultaTO();
    try {
        Arrays.asList(TipoDebitoMulta.values()).forEach(tipoDebito -> {

            final br.gov.pe.tce.spj.data.transfer.TipoDebitoMulta dataTransfer =  new br.gov.pe.tce.spj.data.transfer.TipoDebitoMulta();

            dataTransfer.setId(tipoDebito.getCodigo());
            dataTransfer.setNome(tipoDebito.getDescricao());

            to.adicionar(dataTransfer);

        });
        final Header retorno = this.restMessageHelp.montarBaseHeader("", TipoMessage.SUCCESS);

        to.setHeader(retorno);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
    return Response.ok(to, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

[image: lista]

A lista está sendo carregada na variável `TipoDebitoMulta.values()`.

Eu sei que existe a utilização lambda Java 8 chamada, tentei usar assim:

```
Collections.sort(TipoDebitoMulta.values());
```

Porém não tive sucesso e gerou um erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
@GET
@Path("/tipos-debitos")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Permission(grupo = {Grupo.ADMINISTRADOR})
public Response listarDebitosMultas() {
    final TipoDebitoMultaTO to = new TipoDebitoMultaTO();
    try {
        Stream.of(TipoDebitoMulta.values()).map(tipoDebito -> {

            final br.gov.pe.tce.spj.data.transfer.TipoDebitoMulta dataTransfer = new br.gov.pe.tce.spj.data.transfer.TipoDebitoMulta();

            dataTransfer.setId(tipoDebito.getCodigo());
            dataTransfer.setNome(tipoDebito.getDescricao());

            return dataTransfer;
        }).sorted((a, b) -> a.getNome().compareTo(b.getNome())).forEach(to::adicionar);

        final Header retorno = this.restMessageHelp.montarBaseHeader("", TipoMessage.SUCCESS);

        to.setHeader(retorno);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
    return Response.ok(to, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

O `Stream.of(...)` cria um `Stream` a partir do array. O `.map(...)` converte um `Stream<TipoDebitoMulta>` em um `Stream<br.gov.pe.tce.spj.data.transfer.TipoDebitoMulta>` ao aplicar o lambda para converter um no outro. O `.sorted(...)` ordena os elementos desse último `Stream` utilizando um lambda como critério para fazer isso. E finalmente o `.forEach(...)` decide o que será feito com cada elemento do `Stream` resultante.

Comment: Muito obrigado, show de bola, funcionou.... você salvou minha vida!